# IFrame embedded 3 levels deep

Tags: javascript, iframe

If you have a main web site (www.website.com). And each site has an Iframe embedded with another URL. So on www.website.com there is an Iframe with a src of www.website2.com. Then within that is another for www.website3.com.  Is there ANY javascipt code that can detect what the MAIN PARENT Domain is. Anything from inside the Iframe at www.website3.com that can detect www.website.com as the domain?

Thanks!

On a side note, is there anything within that Iframe outside of javascript that could detect the main domain. Like..flash, or HTML5, or anything else? Anything that will allow someone to detect the main domain within that 3rd level IFrame.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp ?

Comment: That did not answer the question. The code above tells me whether I am currently looking at something in an iframe, or in the main window. Please read my question above. Thanks!

Comment: I supposed you knew how to take that location. `top.location.href`?

Comment: OK so I can use top.location.href to get the TOP most domain? So even if I am 3 levels deep within an Iframe, it will still detect the top-most domain?

Comment: Also what about Document.referrer? Can I use that (even 3 levels deep in an Iframe) to get the details of the referrer they came from?  Not within the Iframe, but the main window referrer?